# How to replace/make tables to be mobile responsive

Tags: layout, grid, grid-layout

I have been putting a blog/content page together using tables (old fashion I know) but problem being it squashes the content rather than collapsing underneath.

I have used a free html cleaner to replace table code for div code. Which works well only problem there is no style.

I can see I have to use css to style but I cannot see how I am suppose to do so with my version. I don't have access as a developer.

[image]

Is there a way to add the styling to the divs or is there another function on magento which will help with layout?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to add classes to divs ? as in

```
<div class="class-name">
```

then add the style at the top of the page like this

```
<style>
.class-name{color;#fff; width etc..}
</style>
```

Make sure you are not in the WYSIWYG editor, ( like you photo ) click the show/hide Editor button until you have a blank page.

Comment: This makes more sense I will give this a go! Thank you for your response